# Touch pad not detected correctly - Asus X540SA

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

`ASUS X540SA, Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, Kernal 4.4.0-36-generic`

The touchpad seems to be detected as a mouse instead of a touchpad. The touchpad is recognized as a "pointer" rather than a touchpad. It has the basic usability of a mouse, with no ability to use multiple fingers or touch scrolling. Along with this, the mouse moves whenever I try to click with my thumb, due to the touchpad registering my thumb as a mouse movement as well. It is extremely difficult to right click because of this as well.

```
laptop@laptop-X540SA:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FTE1001:00 0B05:0101                      id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

The touchpad is detected as `FTE1001:00 0B05:0101` and there is no "touchpad" setting in my mouse preferences either.

Shown here:

[image]

Is this a problem with the kernel or can I fix this manually?

Comment: This must be some new unsupported touchpad. ASUS likes to use new devices each time.

Comment: `0x0b05` is `ASUSTek Computer, Inc` according to http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids, but there is no known device from that vendor with id `0x0101`. So the trackpad is a fairly new hardware. You may want to contact ASUS directly to see if they can give you a driver for Linux.

Comment: Listing the device under "Virtual core pointer" is correct. Touchpad is a pointing device.

Comment: @darksky ASUS does not support linux officially. The latest Focaltech driver has been written by a laptop user Mathias Gottschlag. Hopefully someone who can write a driver will buy a laptop with this touchpad.

Comment: Is there a way to configure the touchpad in terminal to have the same usability that it would have if it had drivers?

Answer (score 2):

This touchpad is not supported yet by any Linux kernel.

There is a driver for this touchpad in [this git repo](https://github.com/vlasenko/hid-asus-dkms)

Answer (score 1):

I suffered this same issue for a while. Same computer. Had backlight and various ACPI issues. The touchpad worked but when trying to fix the ACPI issues, the touchpad would display as yours did.

In case you are still struggling with this, the 4.9-rc1 kernel fixed the touchpad issues and the ACPI issues with the backlight and battery status on the ASUS X540SA.

After installing the kernel from the mainline PPA and running evtest:
[evtest results screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K3Aq.png)

[4.9-rc2](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/10/23/203) has been released as of October 23 and includes several Asus related fixes. I have yet to confirm that it does not break what rc1 fixed.

Comment: I've installed 4.9-rc1 (`Linux laptop-X540SA 4.9.0-040900rc1-generic #201610151630 SMP Sat Oct 15 20:33:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`) using this guide - http://www.yourownlinux.com/2016/10/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-9-rc1-in-linux.html

However, the touchpad is still not getting read and there's still no trackpad preference window.

Evtest results: https://i.gyazo.com/c3d3ea583863cf4b78631bfffc3d1842.png

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have become extremely annoyed at the touchpad changing my cursor position as I try to type, so I've searched all over the internet just to try and disable it. I have Linux Mint 18 installed with kernel 4.4.0-45. I did the following to make it easy to toggle the touchpad state.

`sudo apt-get install xinput`

`xinput -list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FTE1001:00 0B05:0101                      id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

- Look for the id of the touchpad, in my case it's 14. I wrote a small shell script to turn the touchpad off and on.
- TouchPad off:

  `cd /usr/local/bin`
  `sudo nano touchpad-off`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  xinput --set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 0
  echo touchpad off
  ```
- TouchPad on:

  `sudo nano touchpad-on`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  xinput --set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 1
  echo touchpad on
  ```
- Make the scripts executable with:

  ```
  chmod +x touchpad-off
  chmod +x touchpad-on
  ```

  Now you can easily toggle the touchpad state with `touchpad-off` and `touchpad-on`.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually supported in Linux 4.7.5 with basic features only (2-finger scrolling doesn't work for example).
I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and got an Asus Zenbook Pro UX501V.

Comment: It is supported in 4.4 as well in mouse mode. This is not an answer.